# Difftime in R with missing times: how to add 'na.rm=TRUE'?

Tags: r, difftime, na.rm

I would like to use difftime() to extract the difference between two date/time variables which are as.posixct. But sometimes one (or both) of the values are missing (NA), just like below.

```
Start time             Antibiotic time
2016-06-28 08:36:00    NA
2019-10-30 10:43:00    2019-10-30 10:11:56
NA                     NA
```

I want: start time - antibiotic time
Like:
Antibiotica$ABS <- difftime(Antibiotica$StartTime, Antibiotica$AntibioticTime, units=c("mins"), na.rm=TRUE)

But now, I get an error. I think it is because of the wrong use of na.rm=TRUE.
How to add this in the right way?

Comment: What is the expected result? What is `na.rm = TRUE` supposed to achieve? You can't calculate a time difference from only one time.

Answer (score 0):

As Roland points out in the comments, it's not clear that you *should* remove `NA` values. If there is a start time but antibiotic time is `NA`, then the time difference should also be `NA`. If both times are `NA`, then again the time difference should be `NA`

If you were to remove all the `NA` values in the resulting `difftime`, then you will only get results for those rows with complete data, but then these will no longer match up to your `Antibiotica` data frame. In your little example data frame for example, you would only get a single non-NA result. How would you store that in a column?

From your example, your code should work like this:

```r
Antibiotica$ABS <- difftime(Antibiotica$StartTime, Antibiotica$AntibioticTime)

Antibiotica
#>             StartTime      AntibioticTime           ABS
#> 1 2016-06-28 08:36:00                <NA>       NA mins
#> 2 2019-10-30 10:43:00 2019-10-30 10:11:56 31.06667 mins
#> 3                <NA>                <NA>       NA mins
```

If you're not getting this result, you might need to make sure that your columns are in an actual date-time format (e.g. ensure `class(Antibiotica$StartTime)` is not `"character"`).

If, once you have the calculation and you only want to have complete cases, you can do

```r
Antibiotica[complete.cases(Antibiotica),]
#>             StartTime      AntibioticTime
#> 2 2019-10-30 10:43:00 2019-10-30 10:11:56
```

---

**Data used**

```r
Antibiotica <- structure(list(StartTime = structure(c(1467102960, 1572432180, NA), 
  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
  AntibioticTime = structure(c(NA, 1572430316, NA), 
  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
  class = "data.frame")

Antibiotica
#>             StartTime      AntibioticTime
#> 1 2016-06-28 08:36:00                <NA>
#> 2 2019-10-30 10:43:00 2019-10-30 10:11:56
#> 3                <NA>                <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>